# Corona SDK Continuous Integration

Tags: corona-sdk

Is it possible to build corona applications from console?
Or how can I automate build process?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible, since apps are built only via the Corona client application - your source actually gets sent to Corona's server where it is built, then sent back to you as a packaged application. See [Building your App using Corona](http://developer.anscamobile.com/content/building-devices-iphoneipad#Building_your_App_using_Corona) for more info.